# Fetch json object in web service using Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey

I'm sending a JSON object to my web service, which has internal JSON object too. I'm not able to fetch it in my web service. My client side code is as follows

```
var courseDetails = '{"UserId": "abc","CourseId": "C1","CourseDetails":{"Id": "_26_1","Name": "Group task test (revised)","Description": "Sample Description"}}';
    var obj = JSON.parse(courseDetails);    
    $http({
        method: 'POST',         
        url: 'rest/DB/Save',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data : courseDetails,
        }).success(function (data){
            $scope.status=data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("error");
       });
```

and in my web service,

```
    @POST
@Path("/Save")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String  autoSave(JSONObject obj) throws Exception{

    PersonalisationDao p = new PersonalisationImpl();
    System.out.println("Obj "+obj);
    String result = "failure";
    if(obj != null) {
        String userId = (String) obj.get("UserId");
        String courseId = (String) obj.get("CourseId");         
        String courseDetails =  (String) obj.get("CourseDetails");
        // Problem in fetching course Details 
        result = p.addDetails(userId, courseId, courseDetails);    
    }
    return result;
}
```

Normally it should be a JSON object but, its throwing

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I've tried by casting with JSONObject too but still it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the object that you received in the server side, when you display it using System.out.println("Obj "+obj);

Comment: @BandiKishore I receive the same object, but its casting to Linkedhashmap

Comment: Now I see the issue. When using JSONObject, if there are nested objects then it will always be using a LinkedHashMap to store those nested objects as it doesn't know the hierarchy on how these objects could be nested.
So in your request, will the **fields** always be the same? In which case you can create a POJO corresponding to these fields and accept that object. If not, then you can write a transformer to achieve this. Let me know which approach would you want to take, I can provide a sample reference for that.

Comment: I've tried by casting to LinkedHashMap then converting it to String.

Answer (score 0):

Done by casting to LinkedHashMap initially and then converting into string finally.

```
LinkedHashMap courseDetails =  (LinkedHashMap) obj.get("CourseDetails");
String jsonCourseString = new Gson().toJson(courseDetails, Map.class);
```

Comment: Yes, this was the approach I was suggesting.